# /bin/bash version is too low, how to use a different version of bash to source dotfiles when logging in

Tags: linux, bash, authentication

The /bin/bash (of version 3.0) installed globally is too low to successfully source my dotfiles. I don't have the root permission and have installed bash-4.3 in ~/local/bash-4.3, but how could I instruct the computer to use the newer version of bash upon logging in?

Comment: run the `chsh` command to configue your default shell.

Comment: @nos Didn't know that command before. thx .. But I see that the command has to be listed in `/etc/shells` which is only writable by root again ;) ....

Comment: Really seems like a human problem more than anything, talk to your sys admin and get them to update the default shell (3.0 is pretty old). `chsh` should probably work without root, though certain administrators will choose to block it for various reasons.

Answer (score 3):

The startup shell for every user on a Linux system is configured in `/etc/passwd`. You need to be root in order to change that or use the `chsh` command. However the `chsh` command allows you to choose only between shells listed in `/etc/shells` but this file is writable but root only.

But however, you may launch the newer version in the first line of your `.bashrc`:

```
if [ $BASH_VERSION == "3.0" ] ; then
    ~/local/bash-4.3
    exit $?
fi

# ...  other lines will be processed by the newer shell
```

However, this is a hackish solution, far from a usual setup. You should ask your admin to install bash 4.3.

Answer (score 1):

Your shell used upon login is decided by the default shell of the user (you). You may be able to change the setting of default shell to whatever you want. You may refer to http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-change-linux-unix-freebsd-login-shell/

Comment: Subject to the shells listed in `/etc/shells`, which the user does not have access to.

Comment: @chepner In general, you do not need root permission to change your own shell via `chsh`. Of course the admin could configure it however he wants and stop the user from switching to custom shell types in his home-directory or from changing shell at all, but that's by no means default.

Comment: The question is how to use a locally installed shell that does not appear in `/etc/shells` as the default shell. `chsh` is not the answer to that question.

Comment: @chepner I checked the man page of `chsh` again. As shown in http://linux.die.net/man/1/chsh , "chsh will accept the full pathname of any executable file on the system. However, it will issue a warning if the shell is not listed in the `/etc/shells` file. On the other hand, it can also be configured such that it will only accept shells listed in this file, unless you are root." So without further information regarding the configuration of the system, `chsh` is an answer to the question.

Comment: I've edited the answer to reflect the possibility of using `chsh`, subject to local configuration, and rescinded my downvote.